# Adjusting stroke width for square and rectangle tool in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I am creating a favicon via Inkscape using "icon_16x16".  I would like to put a border around the image and fill it in with another color.  I have attempted to use the "square and rectangle" tool but soon found that I did not like the stroke size.

Is there any way I can adjust the width of the stoke?

Comment: http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Stroke.html

Comment: You should put this as an answer so we can mark this question as solved one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Stroke style](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Stroke.html)

> Stroke width can be changed by using the Stroke style tab in the Fill
>   and Stroke dialog, or by using the Style Indicator via a pop-up menu
>   or by Stroke gestures.